# await while loop in asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How to await while loop? I have the following code snippet:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
import time

running = True

async def f1():
    global running
    print(f"Running: {running}")
    print("f1() started.")

    ### await the while loop below
    while running:
        print(f"Inside while loop")
    ###

    print(f"Running: {running}")
    print("f1() ended")

async def f2():
    global running
    print("f2() started.")
    
    # this should be blocking code
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    print("f2 ended.")
    running = False

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Basically, what I want is:

```
# 1. Start f1(). f1() has a while loop.
# 2. Start f2().
# 3. Notify f1() to break the while loop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to put in some await `asyncio.sleep(0)` or so into the `while loop`, not sure if it works with `0` but just put a small number. It just has to be some await call that gives others the chance to do

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
import time

running = True


async def f1():
    global running
    print(f"Running: {running}")
    print("f1() started.")

    ### await the while loop below
    while running:
        print(f"Inside while loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    ###

    print(f"Running: {running}")
    print("f1() ended")


async def f2():
    global running
    print("f2() started.")

    # this should be blocking code
    time.sleep(0.5)

    print("f2 ended.")
    running = False


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(f1(), f2())


asyncio.run(main())
```

that works for me

Answer (score 1):

Without globals:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import sleep
import time


async def f1( q ):
    print("f1() started.")

    ### await the while loop below
    ## Start listener
    event = asyncio.ensure_future( q.get() )
    while True:
        print( "Inside While Loop" )
        if event.done():
            break
        else: 
            await asyncio.sleep( 0.01 )

    ###

    print("f1() ended")

async def f2( q ):
    print("f2() started.")
    
    # this should be blocking code
    time.sleep( 3 )
    
    print("f2 ended.")
    await q.put( 1 )

async def main():
    q = asyncio.Queue( 1 )
    await asyncio.gather(f1( q ), f2( q ))

asyncio.run(main())
```

But, since f2 is blocking it wont actually print "Inside event loop" while it is being blocked

So you'll get output like

```
f1() started.
Inside While Loop
f2() started.
f2 ended.
Inside While Loop
f1() ended
```

Also you can put just about anything in that queue, doesnt have to be `1`.

Comment: Also, if you don't want the blocking function to be blocked you _can_ put it in an executor and await it that works wonderfully